# How can I present display-friendly relationships?

Tags: relationships, order

I am creating an order management system in Salesforce. I have created a custom object called MyProducts which has the following fields:

- MyProductId (An autonumber field - MP-0001)
- Product Name
- Release Quarter
- Release Date

On the Order form, I want to select a product. Right now, the unique identifier is the Autonumber which is in the form MP-0001. I have managed to change the lookup page to show more that one field, but when displaying an order, all I can show is MP-0001 which is not very user friendly.

How can I show more than one field from a relationship?

I am on Professional Edition so I can't write visualforce pages.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to display the additional fields once the record is saved or right after a user selects the product from the lookup? If you have to display on the edit page itself (i.e. just after the user has selected the product), then it would not be possible without VF pages. If you need to display the information after the order is saved, then you can create a Formula field on the Order object which references the fields on the product object.